# Bash - How to execute paths from file

Tags: bash

How i could execute paths from `.txt` in my script?

For Example:

###################

`foo.txt`

`/home/foo_1/public/`

`/home/foo_2/public/`

[...]

`/home/foo_n/public/`

Then I want my script to look for optional file in  every path from the .txt.
How I can do this?

Some loop?

Greetings

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? It is not clear what do you expect to do with the paths written in your txt file.

Comment: What does it _mean_ to "execute [a] path" at all? Paths are generally not executable (the execute bit in their permissions mask just allows traversal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using *xargs* and *find* Utilities

Assuming your file has no extraneous data (it's hard to tell from your original post) and holds one directory path per line, you can simply use the `-n` or `-L` flags with xargs. For example, given a source file like:

```
/home/foo_1/public/

/home/foo_2/public/
```

you could invoke *find* like so:

```
xargs -I{} -L find "{}" -name "filename_to_find" < file_paths.txt
```

There may be ways to do this more efficiently, of course, but this seems conceptually simpler to me than writing your own read and loop statements. Your mileage (and input data quality) may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate all of them into a single path variable

```
$ path=$(paste -ds: foo.txt)
```